# How to make vuetify stepper full height

Tags: css, vuetify.js, spacing

How can I make a Vuetify Stepper component fill the entire height of the page?
Starting from the example in [the doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers/#usage) I have tried several things:

- Adding height="100vh" (or 100%) to the stepper component
- Adding a `<v-container>` with `fill-height` around or in the stepper
- Adding `<v-spacer>` between the card and the buttons

Without success. Ideally I would like the spacing between the card and the buttons to adjust with the screen size (hence the `<v-spacer>`). The buttons would set at the bottom of the screen.

[Link](https://codepen.io/Melaine/pen/abZredp) to the draft codpen

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `style` tag with `height:100%`.

From your code:

```
<v-stepper v-model="e1" style="height:100%">
```